# Auto-complete the name using a text-file data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the search box when I write the name it should ask for suggestions from the text file.
For eg: If a user writes "Aka" then the code should check for the words which contain the string called "Aka" and give the suggestion.
I am able to to do it if i am putting data in script itself, like below:

```
$( function() {
    var avail = [
      "abc",
      "akarsh",
      "ads"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: avail
    });
} );
```

But I need to do it using file.. I am not able to it..

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = load('detail.txt');
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
} );
```

HTML:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to ask the _question_...

Comment: Do you want to search the words from the text of text file based on the keywords typed in textbox?

Comment: I am curious to see the implementation of `load` function...

Comment: @Rayon.. ops..  But i need to do it using file.

Comment: @RahulPatel Yes.. Is it possible..?

Comment: Nope, you should have to pass values in json format.

Comment: You should have to pass data in the below format then only you can use data from .txt file.
[ 
  {"name": "Afghanistan", "code": "AF"}, 
  {"name": "Aland Islands", "code": "AX"}, 
  {"name": "Albania", "code": "AL"}, 
  {"name": "Algeria", "code": "DZ"}, 
  {"name": "American Samoa", "code": "AS"}, 
  ...
 ]

Comment: @RahulPatel – Input can be text or anything which is readable...

Answer (score 0):

you can use select2 plugin, by default return JSON format is (id,text), for eg your detail.txt file is:

```
[ {"id": 1, "text": "abc"}, 
  {"id": 2, "text": "akarsh"},
  {"id": 3, "text": "ads"} ]
```

and for load JSON from file like bellow:

```
$('#tags').select2({
    ajax: {
        dataType: "json",
        url: "detail.txt",
        results: function (data) {
            return {results: data};
        }
    }
});
```